# Jquery to find a name on html page and add hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing

Here is my example:
I have a a website that contains the following:

```
<body>
Jim Nebraska zipcode 65437
Tony lives in California his zipcode is 98708
</body>
```

I would like to be able to search for zip codes on the page and wrap them with hyperlinks like:

```
<body>
Jim Nebraska zipcode <a href="/65437.htm">65437</a>
Tony lives in California his zipcode is <a href="/65437.htm">98708</a>
</body>
```

Could I use a regex selector to find the string and then wrap the string, or replace it with the new hyperlink?

I am new to Jquery and looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Thank you,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace method on html:

```
$('body').html().replace(/\s(65437)\s/g, '<a href=...' + $1 + '</a>');
```

UPDATE: obviously this example searches only for one specific zip code, but you can adapt the statement by using an array of zip codes and performing a replacement for each code.

Comment: or use `.replace(/\s(\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4})\s/g,` assuming every 5 and 9 digit zip code has an associated page.

Answer (score 2):

this is basically the same as mamoo and Jim posted

slight modifications to the expression and using function instead of $1
for some reason with firebug I get an error trying to use $1

```
var s = "Jim Nebraska zipcode 65437\nTony lives in California his zipcode is 98708";
// var s = "12345 should be but not this 22 or this 9999999 here is a zip 44444, and then some more content and another one 34366 and so on";
var result = s.replace(/(\b\d{5}-\d{4}\b)|(\b\d{5}\b)/g, function (thisMatch) {
  return "<a href='/" + thisMatch + ".htm'>";
});
```

this still will not handle leaving a 5 digit street address alone, i.e. 12345 Main St. will end up with a link to 12345

**UPDATE:** changed the regex to avoid greedy handling of 9999999

```
from: /(\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})/g
to:   /(\b\d{5}-\d{4}\b)|(\b\d{5}\b)/g
```

seems to leave the 9999999 alone as desired

Comment: Thanks guys, I will give it a try...

this stuff is great